# using rvest to scrape webpage

Tags: html, r, xpath, rvest

I am trying to scrape the table on the times higher education

[link](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/rankings/united-states/2018#!/page/0/length/-1/sort_by/stats_salary/sort_order/desc/cols/stats)

I have used the following code but the result is an empty table. What am I doing wrong?

```
pacman::p_load(rvest)

webpage <- read_html(paste0('https://www.timeshighereducation.com/rankings/', 
                            'united-states/2018#!/page/0/length/-1/sort_by/', 
                            'stats_salary/sort_order/desc/cols/stats'))


d <- html_nodes(webpage, xpath = '//table') %>% 
  html_table()

d

[[1]]
 [1] rank order           Rank                  Name                  Node ID              
 [5] Overall                                     Resources                                  
 [9] Engagement                                  Outcomes                                   
[13] Environment                                                                            
[17]                                                                                        
[21] Tuition and Fees      Room and Board        Salary after 10 years
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the data! It turns out that timeshighereducation.com uses a javascript to call the data, so using a typical rvest routine will not work.

I found the link below useful to see how to work with webpages displaying data using javascript: [rvest and V8](https://datascienceplus.com/scraping-javascript-rendered-web-content-using-r/)

My first take was to see which node returns the script I want. It appeared to be the number 9 in the lists. I then converted that to html text.

```
t <- html_nodes(webpage, 'script') %>% 
  '['(9) %>% 
  html_text()
```

Upon further inspecting the html text, I found that there is a json file inside the script. And I can actually see the data if I typed the url in Chrome.

So it seemed pretty easy to get the data with many avaialable R packages that deal with JSON. I chose `jsonlite`. It's as easy as it gets, just 5 lines of code to get the data. I am now very happy :)

```
library(jsonlite)
college_json <- fromJSON(paste0(
  'https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/the_data_rankings/', 
  'united_states_rankings_2018_limit0_efdb24148bae97278bbfe6ecfd71cdd9.json'))

college_dat <- college_json$data
```